# How can i generate or create a sequence of word files using excel macro?

Tags: vba, excel, xls

How can i create a sequence of word files with file name as cells in B(2-9999) ?

I am able to generate files but it gets saved as 1,2,3,4....

Eg

```
A       B
Title   Titletopic
11111   Fantasy Golf Resort
222     Golden Palms Resort & Spa
3333    Guest Line Hotels & Resorts
4444    Parkfield Resotel
555     Shreyas Retreat
666     Patels Inn
777     Plantation Trails
888     giri
9999    neil
```

my code is

```
Sub ControlWord()

    Dim appWD As Word.Application

    Set appWD = CreateObject("Word.Application.12")
    appWD.Visible = True

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    FinalRow = Range("A9999").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To FinalRow
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select

        Range("A" & i & ":B" & i).Copy


        appWD.Documents.Add

        appWD.Selection.Paste

        appWD.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:="" & i

    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your using the counter variable not the cell value, so you assuming want `"11111 Fantasy Golf Resort.docx"`

```
appWD.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:= Range("A" & i).Value & " " & Range("B" & i).Value
```

Or alternatively assuming the 1st cell of interest is "A2";

```
dim cell as range
for each cell in range("A2", range("A2").end(xldown))
    ...
    ...
    appWD.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:= cell.value & " " & cell.offset(0, 1).value
    ...
next
```